# Qual è il senso di "giro di lancetta" in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> E pieno di una tumultuosa gioia, lo sguardo di Felice la seguì fino allo svoltare il passaggio Méndez Vigo; poi lei s'arrestò, e come a sentirsela venire quella premonizione, anche il cuore di Felice sembrò fermarsi: un non alto ma corpulento giovane le mosse incontro, e insieme disparvero. Stare nei cenci di Felice in quel **giro di lancetta** successivo non era augurabile a nessuno.

La mia domanda è sul significato dell'espressione "giro di lancetta" in questo brano. Ho cercato il significato di "lancetta" in parecchi dizionari e immagino faccia riferimento alle lancette di un orologio, ma non ho trovato il significato di questa locuzione in senso figurato. Dal contesto, suppongo che il suo senso sia più o meno quello di "situazione" o "situazione spiacevole". È così?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L’espressione **giro di lancetta** o anche **giro di orologio** indica generalmente un minuto o in senso figurato un breve lasso di tempo.

Nel contesto da te citato il significato è che non sarebbe stato piacevole per nessuno essere nei panni di Felice in quel particolare momento.

Comment: Ah! E forse "giro di orologio" è più comune?

Comment: @Charo Giro di orologio si sente spesso nelle telecronache calcistiche, di solito quando sta per finire il tempo regolamentare ovvero _l’ultimo giro di orologio_.